# Add action to dynamically created button in JDialog

Tags: java, swing

I have created and added added a button to JDialog as follows:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
dialog.add(new JButton("test"));
```

This adds the button JDialog. But is there anyway I could add `ActionListener` to it?

I know this is possible if I create a whole new button itself like:

```
JButton button = new JButton("test");
button.addActionListener....
dialog.add(button);
```

But I am wondering if I can do without this.

So far I reached to the point `dialog.getRootPane().getContentPane().getComponent(1)` but stuck here with no idea on a way to implement an actionListener. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "creating a whole new button itself"? To write fewer lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to add listeners while initializing the JButton.

Initializing the button and adding the listener will do as you said.

The other way, you can have an utility method to create a JButton with listeners as below.

```
dialog.add(getButton("Test", new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // Action Logic
    }

}));

private JButton getButton(String name, ActionListener listener) {
    JButton button = new JButton(name);
    button.addActionListener(listener);

    return button;
}
```